# class connection database mysql vb net 2013

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I already made simple class connection to database for mysql for VB NET 2013. But I still dont know how to fill the result from database to datagridview.

This is my database connection class VB .NET 2013.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data

Public Class MainClass
    Public SQLConn = New MySqlConnection()
    Public SQLQuery As String
    Public Data As DataGridView
    Public SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Public SQLAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public SQLData As New DataTable

Public Sub BukaDB()
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
            & "user id=root;" _
            & "password=root;" _
            & "database=tikindonew"
    SQLConn.Open()

End Sub

Public Sub ProsesQuery(SQLQuery, Data)
    SQLCommand.Connection = New MySqlConnection
    SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLQuery
    SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = SQLCommand
    SQLAdapter.Fill(SQLData)
    Data = SQLData
End Sub

Public Sub TutupDB()
    SQLConn.Close()
    SQLConn.Dispose()


End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the code inside Button in Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SQL As New MainClass()
        SQL.BukaDB()
        SQL.ProsesQuery("select * from stok_konos", DataGridView1.DataSource)
        SQL.TutupDB()
End Sub
```

The Question is why I always got error when I try to fill the data from database to DataGridView1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: The connection database is no error... i just dont know how to fill the database result to datagridview. do you have solution about above class? or is there any something wrong in above class?

Comment: error message is so many.. but the point error is at line  SQLAdapter.Fill(SQLData)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'XStudio' (using password: NO)

Comment: i have already fix this.. the problem is public sub should be change into public function.. :)